# Start Order by data from table that is found in another table

Tags: sql, codeigniter

My question may be not easy to explain but I am going to do my best.
I have 3 tables :

1. medicine
2. patient
3. patient_medicine

the third table contains 3 columns :

1. auto increment (id)
2. medicine_id
3. patient_id

I make a query that display all data in medicine table and if there is a patient id found in patient_medicine table I check it and those that are not found are not checked.

A- controller

```
public function showPatientMedicine()
{ 
$data['patient_id']=$this->input->post('patient_id');
$data['medicine'] = $this->model_admin->medicine();
$this->load->view('admin/show-Patient-Medicine',$data);

}
```

B- VIEW

```
<table>
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>List</th><th></th>
</tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<?php

foreach($medicine as $row){
$patient_med=$this->db->select('medicine_id')
->where('patient_id',$patient_id)
->where('medicine_id',$row->id)
->get('patient_medicine')->row('medicine_id');

if($row->id==$patient_med){
    $checked="checked";
} else {
   $checked="";
}

?>
<tr>
<td>

</td>
<td>
<input type='checkbox' value="<?=$row->id?>" <?=$checked?> />
</td>

</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

THIS QUERY SHOWS ME ALL MEDICINES AND CHECK THE MEDICINES THAT ARE FOUND IN PATIENT_MEDICINE TABLE

MY QUESTION IS :

**HOW CAN I SHOW ALL MEDICINES THAT ARE CHECKED IN THE FIRST POSITION OR HOW TO ORDER BY CHECKED CHECKBOX ?**

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: The best way to describe data transformations is with sample data and expected results (in well formatted text). https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM `medicine` as a left join (select medicine_id,patient_id from patient_medicine where patient_id = 2) as b on a.id = b.medicine_id
```

Put the above query in your controller, it will automatically sort the result based on patient id, if patient details found. it will return null for all other details in rows except medicine details.

So you can just

```
<?php foreach($medicine as $row){ ?>

<input type='checkbox' value="<?=$row->id?>" <?php echo !is_null($row->patient_id)?'checked':''; ?> />

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Many thanks bro for your help, I applied your codes, now as result I have all rows display the same way  as my codes posted. What I would like is to put the checked in the first position.